# No valid data returned. check that mapping have valid field names error in DataRatpor Vlocity

Tags: vlocity

Getting error "No valid data returned. check that mapping have valid field names" in extract dataraptor when there is no result returned. When we have records then it returns in proper JSON format but in case of no records it is giving response empty braces {} with error in debug log.

Please help I am new in Vlocity and not able to understand why it is giving error.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Me too - did you ever find a resolution? It must be something obvious??